# Windows 10 icon has showed up once but after shutting down the computer, it is not showing

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

This morning after updating the windows 7 which already existed  in my pc, I saw the windows 10 icon in notification panel.  But, there was a problem when I did shut down the pc and the next time after reopening  there was no windows 10 icon. I also reserved the windows 10 for my pc. I have been using dual boot system(windows 7, ubuntu). What can I do about  the updating process?

Comment: No, I have seen the notification icon once,  but what is the reason for not showing the icon and how can I retrieve it? @DavidPostill

Comment: You no longer need the icon as Windows 10 is out and you can update. The process is easily searchable online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that Windows 10 has been officially released, you don't need to worry about the Windows 10 icon that was there.  You can [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool and run it whenever you are ready to do the upgrade.